# I upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 with 15.04 Desktop. Sound no longer works

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

My motherboard is a MSI 760GM-E5I (FX) which uses a Realtec audio chipset ALC888S/ALC889. Sound worked fine on the previous 14.04 version, but hasn't worked since the upgrade. System Settings says I'm configured for "Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-In Audio" - "Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output" but doing the speaker test yields nothing.

I tried

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

to no avail. Also,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

then

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

again. Still no joy.

The Realtec site doesn't offer Linux drivers for this product.

Comment: in case sound would work you would probably have a sort of trouble like it happened already with this malware program "animal" in earlier times in 70ies (80ies) + be patient + and this is typic for things with mouses since the 70ies no matter which system +

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and edit speech-dispatcher file by using the following command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

In here, change `RUN=yes` to `RUN=no`

Reboot and test

Comment: I did use gedit to look at speech-dispatcher but found that RUN=no was already set.